# Verifying foldl implementation in terms of foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I want to verify following implementation of foldl in terms foldr is correct:

```
foldl4 = foldr . flip
```

I used following tests in HUGS:

```
foldl4 (+) 3 []

foldl4 (+) 3 [1,2,3]
```

They worked.

Please suggest any more tests I could do.

Thanks

Comment: Chapter 11 of Real World Haskell: [Testing and quality assurance](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html).

Answer (score 5):

here is a simple test: `foldl (flip (:)) []` should be `reverse`...

if you want to test `foldr` vs `foldl` you probably should not use commutative operations ;)

here is some proof straight from GHCi:

```
λ> foldl (flip (:)) [] [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
λ> foldl4 (flip (:)) [] [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

and as `flip (+) = (+)` you can guess straight from your definition:

```
foldl4 (+) y xs
{ def }
= foldr (flip (+)) y xs
{ flip (+) = (+) }
= foldr (+) y xs
```

---

if you want some *hint* of how to do `foldl` with `foldr`: you should use functions for the *accumulator/state/b* part of `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` - think of *continuation passing* and try to replace the `:` in

```
x : (y : (z : [])
```

with some smart function to get

```
((b `f` x) `f` y) `f` z
```

remember you want to mimick

```
foldl f b [x,y,z] = ((b `f` x) `f` y) `f` z
```

with `foldr` which basically replaces `:` with it's first parameter and `[]` with it's second if you pass `[x,y,z]` as the 3rd:

```
foldr f' b' [x,y,z] = x `f'` (y `f'` (z `f'` b'))
```

and you now want to shift the parens

Answer (score 0):

Those two are **not** the same. `foldl` and `foldr` do **semantically** different things, but `flip` only induces a **syntactic** difference, so `foldr . flip` cannot ever ever be `foldl`.

Something that *is* `foldl` for example (on finite lists) is

```
foldl5 = (.) (. reverse) . foldr . flip
```

That first part might look confusing, but it basically applies `reverse` to the third argument rather than the first.

Comment: On any lists, I believe. You can get `foldl` from `foldr` in various ways; you just can't get a `foldr` that works for infinite lists from `foldl`.

Comment: I am having trouble discerning your meaning between semantic and syntactic here.  `flip f x y` is just another syntax for `f y x`, but I don't know what `flip f` is syntax for.